# Retrieving Dynamic Dictionary of dictionaries Python

Tags: python

hi how can i display each value from the dictionary below

    product = {'barcode': [123, 456], 'Name': ['Milk', 'Bread'], 'Price': ['2', '3.5'], 'weight': ['2', '0.6']}

i want output as:

```
123  Milk  2 

456  Bread 3.5
```

Comment: can you please provide me the code ..for doing so @AnttiHaapala

Comment: i don't want to change further coz i have to modify entire program. The problem is i have a empty dictionary call PRODUCT where i am appending the data taken from user so the dictionary now contains above data and i have to print other output as displayed above. @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

product = {'barcode': [123, 456], 'Name': ['Milk', 'Bread'], 
           'Price': ['2', '3.5'], 'weight': ['2', '0.6']}

df = pd.DataFrame(product)

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['barcode'], row['Name'], row['Price'])

123 Milk 2
456 Bread 3.5
```

**Edit**:

Using pure Python:

```
product = {'barcode': [123, 456], 'Name': ['Milk', 'Bread'], 
           'Price': ['2', '3.5'], 'weight': ['2', '0.6']}

for tup in zip(*list(product.values())[:-1]):
    print(*tup)

123 Milk 2
456 Bread 3.5
```

Comment: Thanxx @srig it worked. and is there any other way to do the same thing without importing pandas?

Comment: @Nabeinzkc, sure. Try: `for tup in zip(*list(product.values())[:-1]): print(*tup)`.

Comment: how can i display print statement and input statement in single line?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: yes worked. thankyou  and how can i display print statement and input statement in single line?